# moment.js 24h format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I display my time in 24h format instead of 12?

I am using moment.js.

I am pretty sure that these lines could have something to do with it.

```
   meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
        if (hours > 11) {
            return isLower ? 'pm' : 'PM';
        } else {
            return isLower ? 'am' : 'AM';
        }
    },
```

How to change it?

Answer (score 553, accepted):

Stating your time as `HH` will give you 24h format, and `hh` will give 12h format.

You can also find it [here in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) :

```js
    H, HH       24 hour time
    h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is always shorter than a DRTL of RTFM ;-) thx for making me quick to find this answer!

Answer (score 49):

```
moment("01:15:00 PM", "h:mm:ss A").format("HH:mm:ss")
**o/p: 13:15:00 **
```

It will convert 12hrs format to 24hrs format.

Comment: It actually convert 12 hr format to 24 hr format. And it works for me.

Comment: It converts 12 hr format to 24 hr format and it looks good.

Answer (score 41):

Try: `moment({ // Options here }).format('HHmm')`. That should give you the time in a 24 hour format.

Answer (score 22):

Use `H` or `HH` instead of `hh`. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
 moment("15", "hh").format('LT')
```

to convert the time to 12 hours format like this `3:00 PM`

Answer (score 7):

`HH` used 24 hour format while `hh` used for 12 format

Answer (score 5):

```js
//Format 24H use HH:mm
let currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
console.log(currentDate)

//example of current time with defined Time zone +1
let currentDateTm = moment().utcOffset('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
console.log(currentDateTm)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this to get time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

If your time is having date from it by using  'LT or LTS'

```
var now = moment('23:59:59','HHmmss').format("HH:mm:ss")
```

** https://jsfiddle.net/a7qLhsgz/**