# Converting 12 hr format to 24 hr format using moment js in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using jQuery timepicker for displaying 12 hr format time on UI. But internally as data goes to server i have to convert that format into 24 hr format. 
How can i do this using [moment js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Here's how my time shown on display

```
07:50 PM
```

I want that to be get converted into in 24 hr format.
I'm trying below method but getting same output as shown on UI.

```
output=moment($(this).val(),"hh:mm").format("HH mm");
```

Please help me out .
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js 24h format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format)

Comment: @mxr7350 OP is formatting the time correctly. They are not creating the correct `moment` object. I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your value is returning `07:50 PM` you need to change the `moment` call to

`output = moment($(this).val(), 'hh:mm A').format('HH mm');`

Notice that I added an `A` after the minutes to tell moment to take into account the `AM/PM` value that follows the time.

Comment: this is what im about to try @adam-beck