# Display 24 hour instead of 12 with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can display 24 hour time instead of 12h. I’d like to take advantage of the calendar() function.

Code:

```
<p className="item__subtitle">{moment(props.note.updatedAt).locale('en-gb').calendar()}</p>
```

Output:

```
Today at 3:17 PM
```

Comment: possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/issues/412

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js 24h format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format)

Answer (score 4):

Default time format is `LT`, so you need to change it to `HH:mm`.([moment/calendar.js at master · moment/moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/master/src/lib/locale/calendar.js))

You can set format for `calendar` in second argument like this.

```
.calendar(null, {
    lastDay : '[Yesterday at] HH:mm',
    sameDay : '[Today at] HH:mm',
    nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] HH:mm',
    lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] HH:mm',
    nextWeek : 'dddd [at] HH:mm',
    sameElse : 'L'
})
```

full code:

```
<p className="item__subtitle">{moment(props.note.updatedAt).locale('en-gb').calendar(null, {
    lastDay : '[Yesterday at] HH:mm',
    sameDay : '[Today at] HH:mm',
    nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] HH:mm',
    lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] HH:mm',
    nextWeek : 'dddd [at] HH:mm',
    sameElse : 'L'
})}</p>
```

If you want to change all `calendar`'s format, you can set the formats as locale customize like this. (from [Customize > Calendar | Moment.js | Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/))

```
// From 2.12.0 onward
moment.updateLocale('en-gb', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday at] HH:mm',
        sameDay : '[Today at] HH:mm',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] HH:mm',
        lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] HH:mm',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [at] HH:mm',
        sameElse : 'L'
    }
});

// From 2.8.1 to 2.11.2 : `moment.locale('en-gb', {calendar : {...  
// Deprecated in 2.8.1 : `moment.lang('en-gb', {calendar : {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will see this behavior if you have not loaded the locale data, because if it can't find `en-gb`, it falls back to `en` (which is equivalent to `en-us` in moment).

Either use the `moment-with-locales` file, or use `moment` and the `en-gb` locale file.