# React Native how to get time in 24h format?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the time of the device in 24h format
and what i get from the system is 12h format here is the code i do:

```
var time = this.msToTime(this.state.time);
        var houresFormated = moment(time.getTime(), ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
        // console.log(time);
        time = time.getTime();
```

and the imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import './Log.css';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    Modal,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import {
    Button,
    Text,
    View,Form,Icon
} from "native-base";
import DatePicker from "react-native-datepicker";
const window = Dimensions.get('window');
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import moment from 'moment';
```

is there a way i can get the time in 24h format instead ?
or to change it to 24h in a view later on ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js 24h format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format)

Comment: As @MattyK14 indicates: use moment.js