# Change DATE_TIME_FORMAT const in JHipster + Angular2+ project

Tags: datetime, jhipster, angular6

I am currently working on a Angular2+/Typescript/Bootstrap project generated with JHipster in which I have an entity "CalendarEvent" that has a startTime field of Java type Instant. 
Today this field looks like this :

[image: startTime field in form]

My problem is that I cannot know if that time is am or pm.
For instance, when I tried :

```
const startMoment = moment(this.startTime, DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
startMoment.set({hour: 18});
this.startTime= moment(startMoment).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

in order to force the startTime hour to 18h (6pm), the form field showed 06:49. I therefore have no way to know if a time is in the morning or in the afternoon.

Now JHipster generated the entity creation/update form, in which the html code of this field is :

`<label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.calendarEvent.startTime" for="field_startTime">Start Time</label>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input id="field_startTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="startTime" max="endTime" [(ngModel)]="startTime" required/>
  </div>`

and the Typescript code (from which I removed few unrelated code):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DATE_TIME_FORMAT } from 'app/shared/constants/input.constants';
import { JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { ICalendarEvent } from 'app/shared/model/calendar-event.model';
import { CalendarEventService } from './calendar-event.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-calendar-event-update',
    templateUrl: './calendar-event-update.component.html'
})
export class CalendarEventUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    private _calendarEvent: ICalendarEvent;
    isSaving: boolean;

    startTime: string;

    constructor(
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private calendarEventService: CalendarEventService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ calendarEvent }) => {
            this.calendarEvent = calendarEvent;
        });
    }

    previousState() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        this.calendarEvent.startTime = moment(this.startTime, DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        if (this.calendarEvent.id !== undefined) {
            this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.calendarEventService.update(this.calendarEvent));
        } else {
            this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.calendarEventService.create(this.calendarEvent));
        }
    }

    private subscribeToSaveResponse(result: Observable<HttpResponse<ICalendarEvent>>) {
        result.subscribe((res: HttpResponse<ICalendarEvent>) => this.onSaveSuccess(), (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onSaveError());
    }

    private onSaveSuccess() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.previousState();
    }

    private onSaveError() {
        this.isSaving = false;
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }

    getSelected(selectedVals: Array<any>, option: any) {
        if (selectedVals) {
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
                if (option.id === selectedVals[i].id) {
                    return selectedVals[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return option;
    }
    get calendarEvent() {
        return this._calendarEvent;
    }

    set calendarEvent(calendarEvent: ICalendarEvent) {
        this._calendarEvent = calendarEvent;
        this.startTime = moment(calendarEvent.startTime).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    }

}
```

Now you can see that the component has a startTime string attribute instanciated like this :

`this.startTime = moment(calendarEvent.startTime).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);`
(with `calendarEvent.startTime` of type Instant). Now in a config file, I saw :
`export const DATE_TIME_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm';`

I thought that by changing the value of `DATE_TIME_FORMAT` to something like `LLLL` (found on [Moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/)) I would easily get a clearer format, but unfortunately, not only it does not change the form format, but it also appears uninitialized by default :

[image]

I also join my package.json and .yo-rc.json that are often asked to people requesting support (if any help) :

package.json

```
{
  "name": "platform-overview-2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for platformOverview2",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.5.4",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "22.2.3",
    "@types/node": "9.4.7",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "browser-sync": "2.24.4",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.2.2",
    "cache-loader": "1.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.10",
    "exports-loader": "0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "0.4.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "5.1.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "jest-junit": "5.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "5.2.2",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "7.0.0",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.14",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.0.5",
    "prettier": "1.11.1",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.20.3",
    "tapable": "1.0.0",
    "thread-loader": "1.1.5",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "4.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.9.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
    "webpack": "4.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.6.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.3.2"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,css,scss}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prettier:format": "yarn prettier --write 'src/**/*.{ts,css,scss}'",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run lint --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "yarn run start",
    "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
    "test": "yarn run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watch --clearCache",
    "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
    "webpack:dev-verbose": "yarn run webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --profile --progress --env.stats=normal",
    "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=normal",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
  }
}
```

.yo-rc.json

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.worldline.app",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.1.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "platformOverview2",
    "packageName": "com.worldline.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/worldline/app",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "455e1315207269bf7ba9685bdba93b4ff0224ba0",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "fr",
      "de",
      "es",
      "ro",
      "zh-cn",
      "pl"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :) !

Comment: Actually I found on this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format that I could replace hh (12h format) to HH (24h format). Now I have DATE_TIME_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm' and my time is indeed displayed in 24h format. However it would be interesting to be able to use every Moment.js format.

Comment: Also this workaround indeed displays in 24h format but nothing indicates it (it appears exactly as on the first screenshot, except that it now shows times >= 12:00).