# How to find the records which is the range of two dates and time

Tags: mysql

I have table and records are like this

```
id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date |start_time | end_time 
1  |1        | 4       |xyz  |2018-08-20  |2018-09-02|5:00 AM     |11:00 AM
2  |2        | 3       |oig  |2018-08-20  |2018-08-30|9:00 AM     |12:00 PM
3  |1        | 4       |sad  |2018-08-30  |2018-09-10|11:30 AM    |3:00 PM
4  |1        | 4       |sfd  |2018-08-28  |2018-09-18|9:00 AM     |1:00 PM
5  |1        | 4       |khg  |2018-08-29  |2018-09-10|6:00 PM     |11:00PM
```

Now, I have to find the start_date and end_date between the range of `'2018-08-18'` and `'2018-09-28'`. So I used below query

```
SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE `venue_id` = '4' and ((start_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28')OR (end_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28'))
```

So I got a output which is correct.

```
id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date |start_time | end_time 
1  |1        | 4       |xyz  |2018-08-20  |2018-09-02|5:00 AM     |11:00 AM
3  |1        | 4       |sad  |2018-08-30  |2018-09-10|11:30 AM    |3:00 PM
4  |1        | 4       |sfd  |2018-08-28  |2018-09-18|9:00 AM     |1:00 PM
5  |1        | 4       |khg  |2018-08-29  |2018-09-10|6:00 PM     |11:00PM
```

Now I have to find the dates and time of the venue_id=4 which is range of `'2018-08-18'` and `'2018-09-28'`and `"5:00AM"` to `"5:00PM"` so I tried query but it's displaying only first two records. I think it should be display three records. right?

```
SELECT * FROM `batch_list` WHERE `batch_venue_id` = '4' and ((start_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28')OR (end_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28')) and ((start_time<=end_time and "5:00 AM">=start_time and "5:00 PM" <= end_time)) OR ((end_time<=start_time and "5:00 AM"<=end_time or "5:00 PM" >= start_time))
```

My expected output is

```
id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date |start_time | end_time 
1  |1        | 4       |xyz  |2018-08-20  |2018-09-02|5:00 AM     |11:00 AM
3  |1        | 4       |sad  |2018-08-30  |2018-09-10|11:30 AM    |3:00 PM
4  |1        | 4       |sfd  |2018-08-28  |2018-09-18|9:00 AM     |1:00 PM
```

Comment: Step 1: Store dates and times as single entities, using an appropriate datetime data type

Answer (score -1):

I think when you created your table, you declared **end_time** and **start_time** columns as `varchar` type, not `time` type. So, it would compare strings. For instance, '9:10 AM' > '9:00 PM' ( '1' is greater than '0').

I created a table and inserted your data. I got the result as you expected.

```sql
CREATE TABLE SampleTable( id int auto_increment not null,
                        list_id int,
                        venue_id int,
                        item_name varchar(3),
                        start_date date,
                        end_date date,
                        start_time time,
                        end_time time,
                        primary key(id));

INSERT INTO SampleTable( list_id, venue_id, item_name, start_date, end_date, start_time,end_time)
VALUES
    (1, 4,'xyz', '2018-08-20','2018-09-02','5:00','11:00'),
    (2, 3, 'oig','2018-08-20', '2018-08-30', '9:00', '12:00'),
    (1, 4, 'sad','2018-08-30', '2018-09-10', '11:30', '15:00'),
    (1, 4, 'sfd','2018-08-28', '2018-09-18', '9:00', '13:00'),
    (1,4, 'khg', '2018-08-29', '2018-09-10', '18:00','11:00');

SELECT * FROM sampletable
WHERE venue_id = 4 
    AND ( (start_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28') or (end_date between '2018-08-18' and '2018-09-28') ) 
    AND ( (start_time<=end_time) and  (start_time between '5:00' and '17:00') and (end_time between '5:00' and '17:00') );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Give me some time to implement it.

Comment: I am inserting time lik 5:00 AM, 1:00 PM, 5:30 PM etc.

Comment: What is data type of **start_time** and **end_time** columns?

Comment: Please share the downvote reason. without reason we can't understand what was the issue in the answer.

Comment: As I mentioned above, that would compare strings to strings. In my example, I've declared **start_time** and **end_time** as `time` datatype.

Comment: So what is the best way to store the time because at client side I have  start_time and end_time  which is  5:00 AM, 1:00 PM, 5:30 PM and I am inserting the same in the database.

Comment: According to [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) , time is stored in 24-hour format. It means there is no "AM" or "PM". You can convert the time to 24-hour format before store it in your mysql

Comment: The first step is to normalise the design. After that, the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: I am  using datatype date for start_date and end_date and I am using this 
 plugin for start time and end time.http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: @Fuong, I tried your whatever you suggested me. I just want to know, Can we display client-side 5:00 AM, 6:00 PM and when submitting It will submit the 17:00 and 18:00 in the database

Comment: @user9437856 are you using JavaScript at client side? I know a powerful library for this purpose.

Comment: I have an input field and using this plugin http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker. I am getting the time

Comment: @user9437856 I'm not familiar with that one. You can use another library like momentjs, converting 24-hour format to 12-hour format and vice versus. [momentjs 24h format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format). use the result and display it with your plugin.

Comment: @Fuong, The plugin you suggested that totally different. I am using that plugin because I am displaying time in the dropdown like the example in the plugin.

Comment: @user9437856 I got that. My idea is you get a value from your plugin in 12-hour format, then use momentjs to convert that value into 24-hour format and save it in your mysql. Do the opposite to display a value in your database to your plugin.