# How to get 24 hour time with moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this the correct way to get all the times in the day? Is there a better way to do it? Also keep in mind that i will be using this time slots to compare if a time will be in between these slots. Thanks!

```
    const startAndEndTimes =[
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(1, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(2, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(2, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(3, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(3, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(4, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(4, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(5, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(5, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(6, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(6, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(7, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(7, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(8, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(8, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(9, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(9, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(10, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(10, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(11, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(11, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(12, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(12, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(13, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(13, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(14, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(14, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(15, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(15, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(16, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(16, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(17, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(17, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(18, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(18, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(19, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(19, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(20, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(20, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(21, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(21, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(22, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(22, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(23, 0, 0)},
        {startTime: apptDate.setHours(23, 0, 0), endTime: apptDate.setHours(24, 0, 0)},
    ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js 24h format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format)

Comment: The `.setHours()` API only pays attention to one number. Furthermore, those calls modify the date; they do not return a new date. Your code is therefore modifying just one date instance over and over again; all the start and end times will end up exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I compare it to as time slots?

Comment: So is JS modifying that date as it goes line by line?

Comment: Yes, `.setHours()` alters the date but does not make a *new* date.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong about what your time values will be; the call to `.setHours()` will return the numeric timestamp value for the updated time. If that's what you want, then you're good to go.

Comment: It does return the timestamp but it also mutates the original Date, which is probably an unintended side effect and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Moment.js has a function for returning an array of times like that, so you're probably on the right track. However, the way Moment.js functions work is to mutate (i.e. change) the object you call them on. So in your code you're basically setting the time of your `apptDate` object over and over again.

Fortunately you can easily clone a Moment.js object simply by parsing it with another `moment()` call: `const newMoment = moment(oldMoment);`.

Also, you can make your code a lot more condensed and easy to read by using a `for` loop to do the work iteratively...

```
const startAndEndTimes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  startAndEndTimes.push({
    startTime: moment(apptDate).set({hour: i, minute: 0, second: 0}),
    endTime: moment(apptDate).set({hour: i + 1, minute: 0, second: 0})
  });
}
```