# How can I convert 22:00:00 to 10 PM or 22:00 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving user input using a type time input:

```
 <input
  type="time"
  id="time"
  name="hour"
  min="10:00"
  defaultValue="18:00"
  max="23:00"
  className="time"
></input>;
```

The time gets displayed as **22:00:00**, but I'd like to display it simply as **10 PM** or as **22:00**.

I tried using react Moment.js like this:

```
 <Moment className="moment">{data.hour}</Moment>
```

but I got **Invalid Date** as a result (data.hour is an hour formatted like 19:00:00).

Is there any straightforward solution to this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: "I tried using Moment.js for this but it didn't work."  Please show the code for this attempt, so we can get an understanding of why it didn't work. If your code is correct, it should have worked, since this is one of the tasks Moment.js was purpose written for.....

Comment: According to MDN, whether to display using 12-hour or 24-hour format value would depend on system locale. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want the browser to infer how the user would likely want this displayed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js 24h format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format)

Comment: @ParthianShot in the case the user wants it in a 24 hour format, how could I make it go from 20:00:00 to simply 20:00?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse and then format your time. Refer to the docs for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#formatting

```
<Moment parse="HH:mm:ss" format="HH:mm">22:00:00</Moment>
```