# Javascript moment HH:mm

Tags: javascript, mysql, momentjs

What I want here is that the record will check from the database and if it is existing within time it will return true, and if not will return false,

What i think the problem here is the **moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm').toDate()** (12hrs) because as you can see in the database the record are (24hrs)

[image]

and the result from convert is **Thu Apr 14 2022 05:43:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)**

```
var {  assignedTo, startDate, duration } = data
//The value of startDate is `14/04/2022 07:11 PM`
var dd_startDate = moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm').toDate()
var end = new Date(dd_startDate);
    end = new Date(end.getTime(end.getTime() + duration));
//dd_startDate = Thu Apr 14 2022 05:43:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)
//end = Thu Apr 14 2022 06:43:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)

var hasExisting = await _data.hasExistingEvent(dd_startDate, end);
        hasExistingEvent: (startDate, end) => {
            return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               .....,("SELECT  name FROM Event WHERE startDate BETWEEN '" + moment(startDate).format() + "' AND '"+ moment(end).format() + "'", 100, function(data){
                    console.log("====RESULT====: ", data)
                    return resolve(data.length ==0)
                })
            })
        },
```

this are the data from the database

[image]

Comment: use HH instead of hh near var **dd_startDate = moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm').toDate()**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970284/moment-js-24h-format

Comment: @atomankion i've already tried the HH:mm it still the same

Comment: how about near  query **moment(startDate).format("HH:mm")** and **moment(end).format("HH:mm")**

Comment: @atomankion iget this `07:21`

Comment: If your input string is like "14/04/2022 07:11 PM" then you need to include the token for AM/PM, so `moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you use the wrong date formatter

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

try

```
('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

From moments.js documentation

| Input | Example | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H HH | 0..23 | Hours (24 hour time) |
| h hh | 1..12 | Hours (12 hour time used with a A.) |

Answer (score 0):

Update hh with HH like this:

`moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').toDate()`   // parsed as hours (12) local time